# Popup iframe src domain name with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I want to popup iframe src(domain) when script load.
I code simple code but it does not working.

```
<html>
<title>Iframe load</title>
<iframe src="https://evil.com/" id="site" width="800px" heigth="700px"></iframe>
<script>
  var siteD = document.getElementById("site");
    alert(siteD);
</script>
</html>
```

When page load its only showing me `[object HTMLIFrameElement]`. But i want to show in popup `evil.com` from src. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: You should use `console.log`

Answer (score 1):

The cause: `alert()` wants to show a string, which is why it applies `toString()` to its parameter, and that does not render any of the properties of the object.

You need to use `alert(siteD.src);` instead:

```js
var siteD = document.getElementById("site");
alert(siteD.src);
```

```html
<iframe src="https://evil.com/" id="site" width="800px" heigth="700px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple answer to your question, `siteD` has a property `src` which you need to be alerting instead of `siteD` on its own.

Here is an example with src as property: https://codepen.io/dwaynehulsman/pen/rNxYYWQ